# Updating values of nested dictionary is reflected in parent dictionary

Tags: python

I hit this behaviour when parsing through nested dictionaries. Basically a nested dictionary is acting as if it has a pointer. But pointers do not exist in Python?

```
>>> dict1 = {'k1':'v1'}
>>> dict2 = {'dict':dict1}
>>> print(dict2)
{'dict': {'k1': 'v1'}}
>>> dict1 = {'k2':'v2'}
>>> print(dict2)
{'dict': {'k1': 'v1'}}
>>> ## start again
>>> dict1 = {'k1':'v1'}
>>> dict2 = {'dict':dict1}
>>> ## update dict1 value
>>> dict1['k1']='changed value'
>>> print(dict2)
{'dict': {'k1': 'changed value'}}
```

When I change `dict1`, it is not reflect in `dict2`. This I expect.

When I update `dict1`, it is reflected in `dict2`. This I did not expect.

Comment: Everything in Python is object references. If you want a copy, you have to make it explicitly.

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be oversimplifying this, but here goes: when you do the second assignment to `dict1` here: `dict1 = {'k1':'v1'}`, you're essentially creating a new object with the name `dict1` while `dict2` still retains the information from the original `dict1`

But when you do the update: `dict1['k1']='changed value'` you're modifying the already existing `dict1` object in-place, which is why that change is reflected in `dict2`

```
dict1 = {'k1':'v1'}
dict2 = {'dict':dict1}
print(id(dict1))  # print the object ID of dict1
print(dict2)

dict1 = {'k2':'v2'}  # reassign dict1
print(id(dict1))  # new ID, new dict1! Aha!
print(dict2)
```

```
# start again
dict1 = {'k1':'v1'}
dict2 = {'dict':dict1}
print(id(dict1))  # print the ID of the "new" dict1

# update dict1 value
dict1['k1']='changed value'
print(id(dict1))  # same ID as above, same dict1!
print(dict2)
```

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense, and the example helps. thx

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {"k1": "v1"}    # assign a dict the name `dict1`                      
dict2 = {"dict": dict1} # assign a different dict object the name `dict2` whose value is the object stored under name `dict1`                                                                              
print(dict2)            # print what's stored in the memory under `dict2` name                                                                                
dict1 = {"k2": "v2"}    # reassign name `dict1` to a new object in memory                                                                             
print(dict2)            # print what's stored in the memory under `dict2` name                                                                                
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                        
dict1 = {"k1": "v1"}           # reassign name `dict1` to same object as before                                                                         
dict2 = {"dict": dict1}        # reassign name `dict2` to same object as before                                                                         
dict1["k1"] = "changed value"  # access object stored under name `dict1`, change value stored in slot mapped to "k1"                                                                         
print(dict2)
```

In all these lines, "name" refers to the concept discussed in https://realpython.com/python-variables/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if you want to update `dict2` with updating `dict1`, you first initialize `dict2` and then substitute `dict1` like below:

```
>>> dict2 = {'dict':{'k1':'v1'}}
>>> dict1 = dict2['dict']
>>> dict1 is dict2['dict']
True
>>> dict1.update({"k2":"v2"})
>>> dict1.pop("k1")
'v1'
>>> dict1
{'k2': 'v2'}
>>> dict2
{'dict': {'k2': 'v2'}}
>>>
```

Comment: I think OP was mostly asking about *why* this happens, but you're not wrong!

Comment: Yeah , that was just a suggestion :)